# why yes command not working in git clone?

Tags: ssh

i am trying to run script that clone repository and then build it in my docker.

And it is a private repository so i have copied ssh keys in docker.
but seems like below command does not work.

`yes yes | git clone (ssh link to my private repository.)`

When i manually tried to run script in my local system its showing the same.but it works fine for other commands.

I have access of repository as i can type yes and it works.

But i can't type yes in docker build.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `yes` you'd better fix the source of the problem (add or replace SSH host key). 1st, [edit] and replace the image with full text of the error. 2nd, search for the error message and try something from the answers…

Comment: Does your script run in a Dockerfile? Then you may want to add a command to create `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with the line(s) for your repo. If your server's signature is in that file that question will not popup.
Easiest way to find out what the content of the file should be, is to run interactive bash in a temporary container, connect to your server via ssh, confirm with yes manually. Then copy the file or its contents (it's text) out of the container and add it to your script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely an ssh issue.  When ssh is connecting to a host for the "first time",<sup>1</sup> it obtains a "host fingerprint" and prints it, then *opens `/dev/tty`* to interact with the *human user* so as to obtain a yes/no answer about whether it should continue connecting.  You cannot defeat this by piping to its standard input.

Fortunately, ssh has about a billion options, including:

- the option to obtain the host fingerprint in advance, using `ssh-keyscan`, and
- the option to verify a host key via DNS.

The first is the one to use here: run `ssh-keyscan` and create a `known_hosts` file in the `.ssh` directory.  Security considerations will tell you how careful to be about this (i.e., *you* must decide how paranoid to be).

---

<sup>1</sup>"First" is determined by whether there's a host key in your `.ssh/known_hosts` file.  Since you're spinning up a Docker image that you then discard, every time is the first time.  You could set up a docker image that has the file already in it, so that *no* time is the first time.